# Updating Values on json file A using reference on file B

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm not sure how i could achieve this, but i have a  file with 50/60k lines with the following structure:

```
{test_id: 12345, test_name: '', test_time: 213123}
{test_id: 12346, test_name: '', test_time: 331233}
```

And, i have this second file with the reference id for each country:

```
{test_id: 12345, test_name: 'test_a'}
{test_id: 12346, test_name: 'test_b'}
```

so, Using the test_id as reference, what would be the most effective way to cross those two files in order to update the test_name field from file A ?

**Expected result after crossing id's:**

```
{test_id: 12345, test_name: 'test_a', test_time: 213123}
{test_id: 12346, test_name: 'test_b', test_time: 331233}
```

Using sed or awk would be prefered way to achieve this.

Comment: Are the files in the same order and of the same length?

Comment: @vikramls nop, the only thing in common on those files are the id.

Comment: How come that `test_b` ends up in a line with  `test_id: 123456` when second file has it listed like `{test_id: 12345, test_name: 'test_b'}`.  It do not see the connection here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ match($0,/'[^']*'/) }
NR==FNR { id2name[$2] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); next }
{ print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) id2name[$2] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }

$ awk -f tst.awk fileA fileB
{test_id: 12345, test_name: 'test_a', test_time: 213123}
{test_id: 12346, test_name: 'test_b', test_time: 331233}
```

Comment: Worked ! Thanks a lot Ed!

Answer (score 1):

If the first file name is temp.txt that has all information except test name, and the second file name is temp1.txt that has text name information, following command will do what you want and store the result file in res.txt.

```
  awk 'BEGIN 
{ while(getline < "temp1.txt" ) { codes[$2] = substr($4, 0, length($4)-1) } } 
{ printf "%s %s %s %s, %s %s \n",  $1, $2 , $3, codes[$2] , $5 , $6 }'  temp.txt > res.txt
```

Comment: it will also spin off into an infinite loop in some situations. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline.