# Updating Values on json file A using reference on file B - The return

Tags: awk, sed

Ok, i should feel ashamed for that, but i'm unable to understand how awk works...

A few days ago i posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641511/updating-values-on-json-file-a-using-reference-on-file-b/28649080#28649080) which questions about how to replace fields on file A using the file B as a reference ( both files have matching ID's for reference ).

But after accepting the answer as correct ( Thanks Ed !) i'm struggling about how to do it using this following pattern:

File A

```
{"test_ref":32132112321,"test_id":12345,"test_name":"","test_comm":"test", "null_test": "true"}
{"test_ref":32133321321,"test_id":12346,"test_name":"","test_comm":"test", "test_type": "alfa"}
{"test_ref":32132331321,"test_id":12347,"test_name":"","test_comm":"test", "test_val": 1923}
```

File B

```
{"test_id": 12345, "test_name": "Test values for null"}
{"test_id": 12346, "test_name": "alfa tests initiated"}
{"test_id": 12347, "test_name": "discard values"}
```

Expected result:

```
{"test_ref":32132112321,"test_id":12345,"test_name":"Test values for null","test_comm":"test", "null_test": "true"}
{"test_ref":32133321321,"test_id":12346,"test_name":"alfa tests initiated","test_comm":"test", "test_type": "alfa"}
{"test_ref":32132331321,"test_id":12347,"test_name":"discard values","test_comm":"test", "test_val": 1923}
```

I tried some alterations with the original solution but without success. So, Based on the Question posted before, how could i achieve the same results with this new pattern?

PS: One important note, the lines on file A not always have the same length

Big Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

After trying the solution posted by Wintermute, it seens it doens't work with lines having:

```
{"test_ref":32132112321,"test_id":12345,"test_name":"","test_comm":"test", "null_test": "true","modifiers":[{"type":3,"value":31}{"type":4,"value":33}]}
```

**Error received.**

```
 error: parse error: Expected separator between values at line xxx, column xxx
```

Comment: In fileB, should the colons be inside or outside of the quotes (i.e. `"test_id:" 12345` or `"test_id":12345`)?

Comment: @EdMorton Outside, i wil lfix it, thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 3):

Parsing JSON with awk or sed is not a good idea for the same reasons that it's not a good idea to parse XML with them: sed works based on lines, and JSON is not line-based. awk works on vaguely tabular data, and JSON is not vaguely tabular. People don't expect their JSON tools to break when they insert newlines in benign places.

Instead, consider using a tool geared towards JSON processing, such as `jq`. In this particular case, you could use

```
jq -c -s 'group_by(.test_id) | map(.[0] + .[1]) | .[]' a.json b.json > c.json
```

Here `jq` slurps (`-s`) the input files into an array of JSON objects, groups these by `test_id`, merges them and unpacks the array. `-c` means compact output format, so each JSON object in the result ends up on a single line in the output.

Comment: perfect! was also about to answer something like that but needed to figure out the right `jq` syntax. Thanks for giving an example! :)

Comment: @Wintermute It seems that group_by will be removed : according to https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: And replaced by `group`, so you can just use that. It's just that my version of jq is apparently too old for `group`.

Comment: ...which is odd, because I have jq 1.4 (the latest version). Could be a documentation error.

Comment: @Wintermute Could you please check the edit that i made? the solution is really really close for what i expect :)

Comment: That's something you should add to the question, not the answer. Anyway, the problem is that there's no comma between the values in`[{"type":3,"value":31}{"type":4,"value":33}]`.